# Android Class Diagram UML

Tags: android, class, uml, diagram, modeling

I'm trying to create a class diagram for an android project.
I want my classes represent the activities, services and interfaces that I will implement.

There are several questions about it on the web, but I couldn't find a definitive answer.

I know that there aren't specific rules for Android and UML, but I have some doubts.

- How can I represent the relationship between an Activity and a AsyncTask ?
- How can I indicate that an Activity has an intent to another Activity ?

Maybe if someone has an example, will really help.

Comment: How about grabbing a good book about UML first before asking such really very basic question?

Comment: How about help me since you wrote a comment?

Comment: Well, now your questions sound more profound and I took back the down vote. Btw: I guess you mean `Activity` _element_ rather than _class_.

Comment: @ThomasKilian In this context, [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is a class, isn't it?

Comment: @sergej Hmm. Activity diagram also have interruptible regions. So I would think that the mentioned activities are UML Activities. And one implements those Activities using Classes. Probably the OP should clarify this.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Oh, I was thinking about the android class "Activity", not about the UML activity diagrams.

Comment: @sergej Looks like your guess was better than mine ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

[image]

- `MyBackgroundTask` **IS A** `AsyncTask`
- `MyActivity` **IS A** `Activity`
- `MyActivity` **HAS ONE** `MyBackgroundTask`

You can use a *dependency* to show that there is an relationship between the `AnActivity` class and the `AnotherActivity` class:

[image]

In this case, it means that the `AnActivity` class requires the `AnotherActivity` class for its specification or implementation. Also, use notes to make it clear.

**Update:**

Another example:

- `MainActivity` **IS A** `FragmentActivity`
- `MainActivity` **HAS SOME** `fragments`. The `fragments` are of type `String`.

[image]

Comment: thanks! I also have an Activity that has a NavigationDrawer, so I change the Fragments. Can I represent that in this diagram ?

Comment: @G_comp Sure, it would be an aggregation: `AnActivity<>->NavigationDrawer`

Comment: but what about the Fragments? I need to represent them ?

Comment: @G_comp I am not familiar with the NavigationDrawer Fragments stuff. Can you show it as source code?

Comment: this link will help http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/ . Basically, when the user clicks on an item from the navigation drawer the fragment is replaced, changing what is displayed on the screen

Comment: can I represent the relashionship between the activity that has a Navigation Drawer and a Fragment the same way as an intent, only writing "replace" instead of "intent" ? Not sure if I made it clear

Comment: @G_comp I can't see a Navigation Drawer in the code. Do you mean `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: this code is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638967/how-to-change-fragments-using-android-navigation-drawer

Comment: @G_comp There is an aggregation relationship between the Activity class and NavigationDrawerFragment class. See [here](http://yuml.me/d71175b9).