# How to represent one activity starting another activity with an intent in a UML sequence diagram and class diagram?

Tags: android, uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

In this simple example I have two activities ActivityA and `ActivityB`.

`ActivityA` is the foreground activity. User clicks a button that executes `dispatchActivityBIntent()` that creates a intent and dispatches it to start `ActivityB`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

These are the diagrams I came up with

[image]

[image]

I found a previous answer discuss about potraying this in a class diagram.

[Android Class Diagram UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975109/android-class-diagram-uml)

[image]

Alternate way. Is this wrong to show like this?

[image]

Comment: Cross posted https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/408984/android-how-to-represent-one-activity-starting-another-activity-with-an-intent

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand and trying to reuse your wording the sequence diagram can be :

[image]

I supposed all messages are asynchronous except of course the creation of the instance *intent*.

The fact the top of *intent* is not at the top of the diagram indicates it is created and does not exist before. To show the message *create* is just a way to do, an other representation is to have a message going to the rectangle of the instance ... but I do not manages that in my tool ;-)

I also supposed the life of *intent* is limited, the X indicates when it disappears

I preferred to replace *Actor* (if I well understand you : the user) by a *Button* because of *User clicks a button that executes...*.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. could you tell me how the intent would be shown in the class diagram?

Comment: @Enzio probably as you did just with the dependency stereotyped *intent*, you can also show the class Intent but you cannot associate it more than with a dependency again, and at that level a dependency has no real meaning. Else you have to enter in more details like in the link you give. The *Intent* management is more about the dynamic point of view (collaboration => sequence diagram etc) rather than the static point of view (class diagram)

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by " just with the dependency stereotyped intent".

Comment: "Else you have to enter in more details like in the link you give" The link gives a very simple class diagram that I added to my answer above. Can I do the class diagram like that and do the sequence diagram as you mentioned? In that case the Intent class given in sequence diagram is not its' own class in class diagram. If you get what I'm saying.

Comment: Also, can you check the alternate diagram I added to the question? Can I show like that without declaring the intent?

Comment: @Enzio your question is "How to represent one activity starting another activity with an intent", where is the intent in your seq diagram ? what means the message stereotyped 'create' ? it is like is activityb is created, but this is false

Comment: Okey I understand now that the final diagram is wrong,  If I draw the sequence diagram as you did, how do I represent the Intent in class diagram. What you mentioned as " just with the dependency stereotyped intent". I didn't understand that part.

Comment: @Enzio if you draw Intent in a class diagram that class will probably be without relation with the other classes, except if ActivityA memorizes it in *startActivity(intent);* but I do not know what *startActivity* does. About "just with the dependency stereotyped intent" this is what is done in https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRlm6.png

Comment: If ActivityA creates the intent, as described in the narrative, shouldn't the  [create message](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html#create) be used ?  And in this case shouldn't a dashed line with an open arrow head. be used instead of the plain arrow for an ordinary synchronous message (p.575 of the UML spec + [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/402017/209774)) ?

Comment: @Christophe as I said in my answer my tool doesn't allow to have the message going to the instance. The OP code is "*Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);*" => the instance is created synchronously, so I used a synchronous message for *create*.

Comment: @bruno Ah! I missed this, sorry. However, going to the instance or not,  the creation should not be represented with a synchronous message even if the creation is synchronous (see references in my previous comment): this practice - even if it’s common - is not compliant with the notation.

Comment: @Christophe again, I don't have the notation for the *create message* in my tool, how can I use a notation not available ?

Comment: @bruno Sorry again! I understood from your previous explanations that the tool didn't have the possibility to go to the instance's rectangle (which btw seems not mandatory in the spec).  I didn't get that the tool didn't support this `messageSort` at all. For the next release?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion uml-diagrams exist to to give you an overview of some software and not to describe a technical implementation details (like dispatch/intent).

I would prefer something like a stat-diagramm where every state is a Dialog or Activiy. The Arrows between the states could be the flow between the pages, labled with the name of the button (or Intent that is used)