# Android navigation drawer with fragments

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I have an activity that extends fragmentActivity that has a navigation Drawer, and three different fragments.

Is there a way to make a navigation Drawer that has different buttons inside each of my fragments?

For example when you enter fragment 1 you will see certain buttons in the navigation Drawer, and when you go to fragment 2 you will see different buttons in the navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

You should just define which options are to be displayed in the NavigationDrawer depending on which current Fragment you're on, using a switch statement or if statement.

Check out this link:
[How to change fragments using Android navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638967/how-to-change-fragments-using-android-navigation-drawer)

Also, from this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

> As per the Android Design guide, any drawers positioned to the
>   left/start should always contain content for navigating around the
>   application, whereas any drawers positioned to the right/end should
>   always contain actions to take on the current content. This preserves
>   the same navigation left, actions right structure present in the
>   Action Bar and elsewhere.

So this type of thing seems like it was planned for when the NavigationDrawer was designed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. Because I'm pretty new at that, if it's not too much to ask, will you be able to add a Sample code? Thx again

Comment: Check the navigation drawer link, it has several code snippets

Comment: I've already manage to create a navigation Drawer in the main activity so it shows in all of the fragments, but what I didn't manage to is changing the buttons in each of them.

Comment: You should be able to swap out the text and the action performed in on click via an if-block that relies on the current fragment selections.