# Android app: 2 problems with layout

Tags: java, android

After ionic and angular i'm trying to develop apps in native java. After setting up a toolbar and a drawer-menu i wasn't able to make it work:

First problem: How can i use my`item`s in my drawer to show different views (in separate .xml files) in the main view.

Second problem: How can i create a view, similar to a full-height snackbar, whitin a text input field?

thank you for your time.

Comment: for your first problem you can use fragments and for second problem you can use custom views, do some search you will find plenty on examples

Comment: ok thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use fragment replacement. So in your main activity layout file create Frame Layout and onNavigationDrawerClick change fragments.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638967/how-to-change-fragments-using-android-navigation-drawer) as example.

2.I recommend you to use Bottom Sheet in it. [Sample](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)

If you need some code recommendations comment here. Good luck

Comment: Thank you. I Appreciate.

Comment: @DavideNale up vote or aprove answer if it's really solve your problem

Comment: Done . Yes it's what i was searching for.